# Javascript: Repeat an action each X minute (zapier)

Tags: javascript, setinterval, repeat, zapier

I'm starting to learn Javascript and I would like to use it with Zapier to do a Discord webhook. I want it to send a message in my server every X minute. So what should I write [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI5lO.png)? I think it's something with SetInterval but I don't know how to use it :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var interval = 60000; //one minute in miliseconds

setInterval(function(){

/*code to execute once a minute*/

}, interval);
```

That's it!

Comment: Can you post the full code? Edit it into your original question

Comment: Well, it's a Zap, so this is just a trigger action, so I just want to trigger a webhook action

Comment: Not enough information for me to know what you're trying to do and what you've done so far towards that goal.

Comment: In fact I want Zapier to use my Discord webhook every, for example, 5 minute to send a message in the Discord server. The part for sending the message is okay but the code that triggers the action isn't .

Comment: you could try using window.setInterval instead of just setInterval https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

```
var intervalMinutes = 5;// fill in whatever number here
setInterval(function(){ 
    // your calling functions code here!
}, (intervalMinutes * 1000 * 60));
```

... not supported in Zapier,
what about:

```
var intervalMinutes = 5;// fill in whatever number here
function doThing(){
    // your calling functions code here!
    setTimeout(function(){
        doThing();
    }, (intervalMinutes * 1000 * 60));
}
doThing();// first call
```